# How to attach volume to pod's post start life cycle hook?

Tags: openshift

The use case trying out is, way to initialize the postgres database after it starts up. I saw the `post` start hooks in the `openshift` pod lifecycle. I can't put the sql statements using `here-document` or in command line ( Docker command fails due to max length issue ).

So looking a option to save the `SQL` statements in a file via `ConfigMap` and attach it to the `post` container before it starts, so that the `psql` command can execute it. I couldn't see a way to attach the volume from the `DeploymentConfig` from the official document. Is there any way I can do it ?

Document I referred - [openshift-doc](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/deployments/deployment_strategies.html#pod-based-lifecycle-hook)

Comment: You're saying the commands were too long to use in a post deployment execNewPod hook?

Comment: @luciddreamz Yes. That's what happens whey i put all in here document on `psql` command. So now trying to put the SQL statements in a file ( via Configmap) and execute it using `psql`. Making that file available to the post lifecycle pod is the trouble i'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to pass the long SQL statements to the `post` life-cycle pods.

Set the SQL statements in the `DeploymentConfig` ENV variable. These ENV variables are accessible inside the life cycle pods also, so then we can easily do the bellow command

```
  post:
    failurePolicy: Abort
    execNewPod:
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - '-c'
        - >-
          echo $INIT_SQL_STATEMENTS | psql "sslmode=allow
          host=postgres user=postgres password=postgres"
      containerName: postgres

  .....

      env:
        - name: POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: postgres
        - name: INIT_SQL_STATEMENTS
          value: >-
            create user haridas with encrypted  password 'haridas';...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option which I've employed in the past is to pass in the sql statements in a parameters file. This will then allow you to more easily configuration manage the sql commands (e.g. check it into git) and declutter your deployment configuration (DC). Here is what I did:

1. Move your post hook to the DC portion of the template file. Let me
   know if you need steps on how to export, modify, and re-import a
   template file, but I didn't want to over-complicate this procedure
   unnecessarily.
2. Add a parameter to the template file called SQL_COMMANDS like this:

> ```
> parameters:
> - description: The SQL commands to run. 
>   displayName: SQL commands
>   name: SQL_COMMANDS
>   required: true
> ```

3. In the post hook code of the template (DC section) run the SQL_COMMANDS like this:

> ```
>  execNewPod:
>     command:
>     - /bin/sh
>     - -c
>     - echo "${SQL_COMMANDS}" | psql -h ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME} -U ${POSTGRESQL_USER} -d ${POSTGRESQL_DATABASE};
> ```
>
> Note the other variables in the command are also passed in as parameters.

4. Create a parameters file similar to this:

> ```
> POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres
> POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=somepassword
> POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=myDatabase
> SQL_COMMANDS="CREATE TABLE Configuration(CONFIGURATION_ID character varying(255) 
> NOT NULL, description character varying(255)
> NOT NULL, key character varying(255) NOT NULL, value text NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (CONFIGURATION_ID) ); INSERT INTO Configuration
> (CONFIGURATION_ID, description, key, value) VALUES ('10', ... etc."
> ```

5. Deploy your app using the template and pass in the parameters from the file:

> ```
> oc new-app <template name> --param-file=ParametersFile.txt
> ```